# How to join a column in SQL based on the same id

Tags: sql

I have two tables that look like this:

Table `Person`:

```
id name
---------
1  Jason
2  Dave
3  Amy
...
```

Table `Points`:

```
id points
----------
1  8
2  9
3  5
...
```

I try to join the "name" column from the first table to the second one based on their ids. The expected outcome should look something like this:

```
id name   points
-----------------
1  Jason  8
2  Dave   9
3  Amy    5
...
```

My select query is:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Person.id = Points.id 
            THEN Person.name 
    END AS name, 
    Points.points
FROM 
    Person, Points;
```

The result I get is:

```
id name   points
-----------------
1  Jason  8
2  NULL   9
3  NULL   5
...
```

How can I modify it to get the desired output?

Thanks in advance for your time and help

Comment: Tip: Provide a consistent [mcve], i.e. sample table data and expected result that match. (You have a `3` and `...` which make the problem a bit unclear.)

Comment: [**Bad habits to kick**: using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: This is SQL 101. *Any* tutorial would have this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` to reach your desired result.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.points
FROM Person AS t1
INNER JOIN Points AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

A complete example is given here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_9lZMVZx)

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are poor table aliases. Choose aliases that make sense, like `p` for `persons` etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.id,p.name,poi.points
from person p
join point as poi on p.id=poi.id
```

Do you need this?

Answer (score 1):

Also try two more joins which is useful in MySQL Database.

```
Natural Join:
select * from person natural join points

Self Join: 
select * from person self join points using (id)
```

[Result](https://dbfiddle.uk/j9bYkFc4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join to solve this problem as it gives matched data from both the tables.

```
SELECT p1.id,p1.name,p2.points 
FROM person p1 
INNER JOIN points p2 ON p1.id=p2.id;
```